# JQuery - Serializar inputs de un formulario

Tags: php, html, jquery, html5, jquery-ui

tengo este formulario con html

```
<form id="search_form">

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="fuelType">Combustible</label>
                        <select id="fuelType" class="form-control">
                            <option selected disabled>Selecciona...</option>
                            <option value="101">Diesel con AdBlue</option>
                            <option value="610">Gasolina</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="brand">Marca</label>
                        <select id="brand" class="form-control">
                            <option selected disabled>Selecciona...</option>
                            <option value="123">VW</option>
                            <option value="322">Opel</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
            </form>
```

Y lo que intento hacer desde jquery es serializar todos los input para enviarlos al controlador de esta forma

```
    $('#search_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
    var data = $("#search_form :select").serializeArray();
    console.log(data);
});
```

El console.log de data me devuelve "nulo", y una pregunta relacionada en var data obtendre solo los "select" pero si tengo "input type" en el form como puedo hacerlo para que me serialize los input y los select.

Gracias,

Answer (score 1):

no te olvides que dentro de tus `<input>`, o en el caso de tu ejemplo `<select>` necesitas agregar el atributo `name`, luego de eso todo esta genial. Saludos.

Con respecto a tu otra pregunta, si pones solo el `$("#search_form").serializeArray();` puedes ver tanto `<input>` o `<select>`

```js
$('#search_form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent form from submitting
  var data = $("#search_form").serializeArray();
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search_form">

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="fuelType">Combustible</label>
      <select id="fuelType" name='fuelType' class="form-control">
        <option selected disabled>Selecciona...</option>
        <option value="101">Diesel con AdBlue</option>
        <option value="610">Gasolina</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="brand">Marca</label>
      <select id="brand" name='brand' class="form-control">
        <option selected disabled>Selecciona...</option>
        <option value="123">VW</option>
        <option value="322">Opel</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="brand">Marca2</label>
      <input id="brand2" name='brand2' class="form-control">
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si bien la respuesta anterior es correcta, me gustaria agregar algo:

1.- ¿Por que serializar un formulario? eso se hacia antes, pero ahora tenemos algo llamado **FormData()** te muestro un ejemplo para que puedas comprender como funciona este objeto:

2.- Primero les añades el atributo `name` a tus `select` esto te ayudara a identificarlos, tus select quedarian de la siguiente manera:

**Select 1**

```
 <select id="fuelType" name="fuelType" class="form-control">
     <option selected disabled>Selecciona...</option>
     <option value="101">Diesel con AdBlue</option>
     <option value="610">Gasolina</option>
 </select>
```

**Select 2**

```
<select id="brand" name="brand" class="form-control">
 <option selected disabled>Selecciona...</option>
  <option value="123">VW</option>
  <option value="322">Opel</option>
</select>
```

3.- En tu evento submit tendrias algo como esto:

```
 $("#search_form").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent form from submitting
  var data = new FormData(this);
});
```

4.- Estamos creando un nuevo objeto de tipo **FormData** y le pasamos como parametro el mismo formulario al cual le estamos haciendo `submit` y lo asignamos a la variable **data**

5.- Para acceder a los elementos tenemos que utilizar get, y nos ayudamos del atributo `name` de tus select ejemplo:

```
$("#search_form").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent form from submitting
  var data = new FormData(this);

  console.log(data.get("fuelType"));
  console.log(data.get("brand"));
});
```

6.- TE DEJO UNA GUIA PARA QUE PROFUNDICES MAS EN EL TEMA SOBRE FORM DATA:

[Usando Objetos FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData)
[FormData Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/FormData)

Answer (score 0):

Para serializar tu formulario completo solo necesitas tener el id del form de esta forma

```
$("#search_form").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $("#search_form").serialize();
});
```

$("#search_form").serialize();

Este serializara tu formulario con todos los elementos que estén dentro de el, solo necesitan tener el atributo name="" en el input o select y listo luego puedes enviar tu petición ajax o lo que desees hacer